# Count is not instantly refreshed on the Jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

While login into java web application, displays a notify 'popup' window with select options 'In, Out and Maybe'. In my 'NotifyAllPlayers'servlet, I used the
getParameter to get the selected value as below;

```
 String soccerAvailable = request.getParameter("soccernotify");
```

later on successfully saving the value into  database and the sending the value to 'listplayers.jsp' via forward operation.

```
request.setAttribute("soccerAvailable", soccerAvailable);
            request.getAttribute("soccerAvailable");
            RequestDispatcher rd = request
                    .getRequestDispatcher("listplayers.jsp");           
            rd.forward(request, response);
```

The problem here is, after saving 'soccerAvailable' into the database, the count is not 'instantly' getting refreshed and displaying in the jsp page.
The count get updated only if the player logout from system and login back.

```
<%String notify = (String)request.getAttribute("soccerAvailable");%>

                                <div id="ply_notify" class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                                <label for="notify"><core:out value="${playerrecord.notify}" /> </label>

                                </div>
```

Could someone please explain where the problem occurs ? Is there any better way to handle this?

Comment: There doesn't seems to be any problem with the code but still you can try to use refresh+no cache functionality  to get updated value

Comment: @Shadab: I have tried the following in jsp, but still its not updating the count instantly <%
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
//prevents caching at the proxy server
%>

Comment: and you used auto refresh funtionality too?

Comment: Yes i have added refresh

Comment: I have no idea then